# How to set the initial value Nil using /: (Not the foldRight)

Tags: scala

The code below doesn't compile because of the type mismatch, and I suppose this can be solved by explicitly giving the type parameter `List[Int]` to `Nil` but I couldn't figure it out how.
(there are some info about the `foldRight` method but I would like to use `/:` here)

```
val li = List.range(1, 10)
(Nil /: li)((a, b) => b :: a) // doesn't compile
(List(0): li)((a, b) => b :: a) // compiles

<pastie>:14: error: type mismatch;
found   : List[Int]
required: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
       (Nil /: li)((a, b) => b :: a)
                               ^
```

Could anyone tell how to fix this?

Comment: `/:` is the equivalent of `foldLeft`, not `foldRight`.

Comment: Ops. I always get confused with these two. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because, when you provide `Nil` as Initial value, you are providing `Nil.type` as **type parameter** and hence you are getting error.

```
def /:[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

If you see the `/:` method definition, it is a **higher order function** that take function `op` as parameter. If you look at the function type for `op` i.e. `(B, A) => B`, the return type is `B`. When you invoke `/:` as `Nil /: li`, the type parameter passed is `Nil.type` i.e. `Nil /:[Nil.type] li`. Hence, `B` is `Nil.type`.

Now, lets look at your function literal for parameter `op`:
`(Nil /: li)((a, b) => b :: a`)
Here, you are returning `b::a` in your function literal. If you look closely, the type of `b` is `Int` since `li` is `List[Int]` and `a` is `List()` (i.e. value of `Nil`). Hence, `b :: a` will return type of `List[Int]`. However, function type `op` expect `B` as return type which is `Nil.type` as explained above but you are returning `List[Int]` type. Hence you are getting error.

When you provide `List(0)` as initial value instead of `Nil`, you are passing `List[Int]` as type of `B` and in your function literal the returned type of `b::a` is `List[Int]`, hence it worked.

```
(List(0): li)((a, b) => b :: a) ~~ (List(0)/[List[Int]] li)((a, b) => b :: a)
```

To avoid this issue, you need to explicitly provide type parameter in `/:` method.

```
(Nil /:[List[Int]] li)((a, b) => b :: a)
```

Comment: works beautifully, and thanks for the detailed explanation. now I got why.

Answer (score 2):

How about using:

```
scala> val li = List.range(1, 10)
li: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> (List.empty[Int] /: li)((a, b) => b :: a)
res20: List[Int] = List(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not lovely but...

```
scala> val li = List.range(1, 10)
li: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> ((Nil : List[Int]) /: li)((a, b) => b :: a)
res0: List[Int] = List(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```